# std::vector resetting upon program initialization

Tags: c++, embedded, c++20, stdvector, crtp

I have the following class that is used to keep track of objects upon creation. These are all objects at file scope with static storage.

```cpp
template <typename derived, std::size_t size = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()>
class ObjectTracker{
  private:
    ObjectTracker(ObjectTracker const &) = delete;
    ObjectTracker& operator=(ObjectTracker const &) = delete;

    static std::size_t total;
    static std::vector<derived*> objects;

    std::size_t id;

  protected:
    ObjectTracker(){
      if(total < size){
        objects.push_back(static_cast<derived*>(this));
        id = total++;
      }
      else throw std::length_error("Too many objects are being created in ObjectTracker subclass.");
    }

  public:
    static derived* getNth(std::size_t n) {return (n < getList().size()) ? getList()[n] : nullptr;}
    static std::size_t getCount() {return total;}
    static std::vector<derived*> const & getList() {return objects;}

    std::size_t getID() const {return id;}
};

template <typename derived, std::size_t size> std::size_t ObjectTracker<derived, size>::total;
template <typename derived, std::size_t size> std::vector<derived*> ObjectTracker<derived, size>::objects;
```

I use it like the following

```cpp
class Auton: public ObjectTracker<Auton>{
//Other stuff

  public:
    Auton(std::string name, std::function<void()> program, E_Reset_Types reset_type = E_Reset_Types::home){
    //saves vars
    };
```

If I check `getList()` during the creation of objects, I can see it correctly filled up. It has the elements in the order of creation, and is the right size.

However in main() calling `getList().size()` returns 0. `getCount()` still returns the correct value, but the vector seems to get reset.

This behaviour is inconsistent. I have 4 different classes that derive from `ObjectTracker`. 2 of them work as expected, and the other two exhibit the resetting vector.

Is there any explanation for why the vector gets reset?

If it helps, this works just fine on my computer, running clang++20. However the issue occurs when running on a VEX V5 in the [PROS](https://pros.cs.purdue.edu) environment which compiles using gnu++20.

Comment: "_These are all objects at file scope with static storage._": `objects` itself is a static storage duration object with unordered dynamic initialization (because it is a class template static member). You can't assume that it will be initialized when you use it during _any_ other dynamic initialization. That would be UB.

Comment: Instead use a static functions with static local variables returned by-reference, e.g. `static auto& objects() { static std::vector<derived*> o; return o; }`.